# Does G.655 fiber supports 1310 nm wavelenght?

Tags: fiber, sfp

I am using G.655 standard fiber for a project. We are using short haul SFP & long Haul SFP. Long haul (1550 nm) works fine with G.655 fiber, But Short haul SFP (1310 nm) is having some issue as link is not getting up. I am not sure whether the issue is coming because use of short haul at 1310nm.

Whether 1310nm wavelenght is support in G.655 fiber with cable cut off wavelenght?

Thanks for help in advance.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: You don't say which SFPs or what distance you are using, but, for short haul, you may need attenuators if the distance is very short.

Comment: It will be transceiver and *distance* constrained. G.655 fiber is designed to minimize dispersion in the 1510/1550nm range. The further outside the "zero" point, the worse dispersion may be. The length of the run magnifies the effect. If you have to correct ($$$$$) equipment, you can measure the distortion (and power, etc.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Cisco switches/line modules/SFP's that support DOM from the cli do `show interface transceiver detail` command and it will show all of the power levels. If your hardware doesn't support DOM you will get an error message. Cisco 1310 -LH SFP don't support DOM. If out of spec it will put either a + or ++ if too hot or - if too low. Definitely have to have the correct SFP reach part or things will be unstable. On 1310 short runs on good fiber loss is very minimal. Very easy to blind the receive side of the optics.

Comment: Hi bsulli, the receive power at SFP is -10 dBm & its sensitivity is -19dBm. But even having a power received, switch physical layer link is getting up. I doubt if G.655 ITU standard FO cable support 1310 nm wavelenght SFP.

Comment: Stand corrected. I was thinking about our single mode fiber which is ITU g.652, .655 does not support 1310nm http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/product_bulletin_c25-530841.html & http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=170740&seqNum=7 last paragraph.

Comment: I'm not convince that G.655 cannot be used for 1310 nm. Cable vendors seem to think it can, and I keep finding things like this: `usable at 1310 nm wavelength and optimized for high bit rate transmission in C (1530 – 1565 nm) et L (1565 – 1625 nm) bands,`.

Comment: Don't disagree Ron as I had experiences where wavelengths worked on fiber that weren't suppose to but if the Cisco docs are to be believe they as a vendor don't support it 1310 on 655 fiber.

Comment: Of course, the OP hasn't said which SFPs  are being used for this, so we don't know for sure if they non-supported Cisco or some other brand/type.

Comment: Very true, could be all non-cisco gear.

Comment: I am facing issue when the distance is getting more than 4 km of fiber. Not working with 1310nm sfp. Below 4 km all is fine

Comment: 655 FO cable datasheet states the cable cutoff wavelenght to be 1360nm. So I guess the problem I am facing is due to non campatibility of 1310nm wavelenght over 655 fiber

Comment: Simple answer is yes. You are using "O" band wavelengths on fiber that is optimized for "C" & "L" bandwidth. I already sent a link earlier of the Cisco transceivers (assuming this is a Cisco network, you haven't said) that support G.655 & G.656. They only support at 1550nm (should be true of all vendors) and that is because of chromatic dispersion coefficient spec for G.655 which is related to the 1530-1565 nm band. G.656 this coefficient has expanded the range in the 1460-1625 nm band, adds "S" to the C-L bands. Your fiber may support .656 as well.

Comment: Also every fiber manufacturer is different. For example Corning specifies 2ps/nm chromatic dispersion at 1550nm, Alcatel 9ps/nm. We use Corning and Commscope almost exclusively because of tight tolerances in their manufacturing process.

Comment: @bsulli - i am using Hirschmann RS30 L2 switch with hirschmann M-SFP-LX/LC. this transceivers operates at 1310nm. Manufacturer has not mentioned anything which fiber it supports.

Comment: Look up the data sheet for the fiber manufacturer as that will be the defining information but my take is these transceivers will not work, as others has mention as well as myself at shorter distances there are times where you can get mismatch optics and fiber to come up. I believe the mismatch is too great for long haul. IMO Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

G.655 fiber like Corning LEAF has a cutoff frequency of 1450nm. Thus if you launch a 1310nm signal it behaves as multimode fiber. It's diffucult to predict how these modes would be transmitted in this situation, but most likely the light won't reach the end if your transmitter isn't powerfull enough.
There are some evidencies like this one http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/nanog/users/153261 where people make 1310nm sfp with optical budget for 40km to pass g.655 fiber of 10km.